# Is Remote Repository equivalent to Central Repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, remote-repository

In Git Version Control System, What are the differences between Remote Repository and Central Repository? Is it only the term that is different but they are actaully the same thing?

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that there's no answer accepted at the duplicate, but all the answers there make valid points. In the end, a remote repository is as central as *you* think it is: no more and no less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually highly depends on the context, but since you mention Git I would assume you meant code repository. If you are talking about remote code repository vs central code repository, then they are the same IMO. Remote Code Repository just meant the repo is not local, it's at a remote location. And since it's a remote location for all the team members, it is central at one place that is shared among the teammates, no one has the ultimate decision but a joint equal privilege repo (obviously you will have admins but that's that)

Hope this helps